# Solution to negative Pell's equations

Tags: pell-type-equations

I was reading a paper on negative Pell's equation (https://msp.org/pjm/1986/124-1/pjm-v124-n1-p09-s.pdf), and I was wondering if it was possible to show for all soluble $X^2-DY^2=-1$, that $Y$ is a sum of two square integers?  (Given $D$ is a sum of two squares).

Comment: How many $4n-1$ prime factors can $y$ have?